# i have a Syntax error: Operator expected in this code in prolog

Tags: prolog

```
%import string
from pylog import*

%RULES

AmmountEarned(_steady,_[steady|unsteady]) :- AmmountEarned(_steady,_unsteady)


min_savings(Dependents, Amount) :-
 Amount is 5000 * Dependents.

min_income(Dependents, Amount) :-
     Amount is (4000 * Dependents) + 15000.

%Strategies
investment(savings) :-
 savings(inadequate).

investment(stocks) :-
 savings(adequate), income(adequate).

investment(combo) :-
 savings(adequate), income(inadequate).

%Logic
%
savings(adequate) :-
 amount_saved(Amount),
 numDependents(Dependents),
 min_savings(Dependents, SavingsMin),
 Amount > SavingsMin.

savings(adequate) :-
 numDependents(Dependents),
 Dependents == 0.

savings(inadequate) :-
 amount_saved(Amount),
 numDependents(Dependents),
 min_savings(Dependents, SavingsMin),
 Amount =< SavingsMin.


income(adequate) :-
 earnings(AmountEarned, steady),
 numDependents(Dependents),
 min_income(Dependents, IncomeMin),
 AmountEarned > IncomeMin.
income(inadequate) :-
 earnings(AmountEarned, steady),
 numDependents(Dependents),
 min_income(Dependents, IncomeMin),
 AmountEarned =< IncomeMin.

income(adequate) :-
 numDependents(Dependents),
 Dependents == 0.
income(inadeqate) :-
 earnings(ammountEarned, unsteady).

amount_saved(22000).
numDependents(3).
earnings(25000, steady).
```

Answer (score 0):

The first line of the program looks like Python, not Prolog. Is this mixing of Python and Prolog in a single file a feature of PyLog?

The line involving `AmmountEarned` is full of both syntax and logic errors. It also has nothing to do with the rest of the program. Remove it.

Also, for the future: Please include the exact error message in the body of your question, not just in the title. If the error message specifies a certain program point (e.g., line number), include that as well.